# GWT Multiple html pages and navigation

Tags: java, gwt

Hi firstly i want to mention that i am aware of ajax based application and reuse of same page.

The requirement here is that, i want to have two separate pages one for login and other for the main application. Now, this is not because i just want it, but because i have very different layouts in the two pages which i am comfortable to put together with html elements and css directly in the page and then putting divs to contain dynamic html for gwt to populate.

Even in case of myfaces i have not seen application with same page for login and the main app page.
Anyways, the problem i am facing is, lets say i have two pages

Login.html with a div : div id="login"

Main.html with a div: div id="main"

i have declared both of them in my welcome file list in web.xml
Now i start with Login page fill the "login" div with gwt widgets and on click of a button
i am using following jsni code to redirect to "/Main.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997"

private native void gotoURL(String url) /*-{ 
    $wnd.location.href=url; 
 }-*/;

and then trying to populate the "main" div. But the behaviour as i noticed is that the application call the entry point again and it doesnt find any element as "login" and gives NPE.
Is there a way to do this? also to get rid of the "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't want to add the `?gwt.codesvr=...` stuff - it's related only to hosted (debugging of gwt) mode. You could use a relative url (for example simply "Main.html"). But since you can only have a single entry point, you need to either split the app into two client modules (two separate apps actually) or dispatch in your entry point according to the url (whether you've landed on Login.html or Main.html)

Second, what I would do in this scenario is have an empty html with no layout except a single div for the dynamic content as the only html page of the app. Then I would use 2 UiBinders - one for the main page, and one for login, and use a hash suffix in the url (using GWT's history event and management, and hyperlink widgets) to know where I am. Maybe you should read more in GWT's documentation on history and stateful apps. Try http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html#stateful

Comment: Hey thanks, the explanation for Ui binders in the docs seems to represent the solution for my problem only, Also the history mechanism seems to be a good option, but since i have only limited pages i went with your first suggestion
RootPanel panel = RootPanel.get("login");
if(panel != null)
  {
   LOG.log(Level.INFO,"login page.");
  }
  else
  {
   panel = RootPanel.get("main");
   LOG.log(Level.INFO,"main page.");
  }