# Maintaining state between multiple entries to same GWT module

Tags: java, gwt

A while ago i asked this question 
[GWT Multiple html pages and navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714747/gwt-multiple-html-pages-and-navigation)

Although i was first satisfied with the simplest solution i used, which is similar to the one suggested here also [Problem with multiple entry Points in the same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929661/gwt-problem-with-multiple-entry-points-in-the-same-module). But a major drawback which i am running into is that, The data which i get and build from the first run of the **onModuleLoad()** is not available in the susequent run of the **onModuleLoad()** for the same **EntryPoint** class. For eg. lets say i create a instance of a class **LoginSessionInformation** on the first run,now how do i access this instance when the **onModuleLoad** is called the second time.
Thanks

**Edit:** This is purely for client side, as i am taking the login information in the first run and constructing class **LoginSessionInformation**, and planning to pass that to server the second time.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the state in the URL token and use the history handler.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html

Comment: hi, this is a completely different approach, in this case i don't think i would have to enter the same EntryPoint again if i use it appropriately with UIBinders, so the old instances will be there already.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said where all your state is.. if its on the server, your in the same session so its all there. If its a client side problem, then one place to store stuff is in a cookie or to probe the server again if ncessary. Many times its okay to leave stuffon the server and do your work there on the data rather than passing back lots of data to the client and doing some processing there..

Comment: will i have the same flexibility as with a java instance if i use cookies? So, the problem is when the application enters the same entry point the second time, everything is reinitialized and the old references for the instances are nulled by gc.

Comment: @ChingPing: That's what the history tokens solve, it is a different approach but you pass in all the values of what you need initialized or a key to where the "save-state" is stored. Think of video games.